# How to fix mail server SSL?

Tags: debian, postfix, email-server, ssl-certificate

Our mail server was originally set up using self-created certificates. However when those expired, and I tried to recreate them, the whole thing just blew up. Since I know it will be important, we are running a Debian server and postfix.

Now I see these errors generated in the mail logs:

```
May 15 08:06:34 letterpress postfix/smtpd[22901]: warning: cannot get certificate from file /etc/postfix/ssl/smtpd.cert
May 15 08:06:34 letterpress postfix/smtpd[22901]: warning: TLS library problem: 22901:error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory:bss_file.c:352:fopen('/etc/postfix/ssl/smtpd.cert','r'):
May 15 08:06:34 letterpress postfix/smtpd[22901]: warning: TLS library problem: 22901:error:20074002:BIO routines:FILE_CTRL:system lib:bss_file.c:354:
May 15 08:06:34 letterpress postfix/smtpd[22901]: warning: TLS library problem: 22901:error:140DC002:SSL routines:SSL_CTX_use_certificate_chain_file:system lib:ssl_rsa.c:720:
May 15 08:06:34 letterpress postfix/smtpd[22901]: cannot load RSA certificate and key data
```

And when trying to access email from a client like Thunderbird from outside our local network, you receive "Unable to connect to smtp server".

I have verified that the file /etc/postfix/ssl/smtpd.cert does exist. The current owner of the file is `root:root`. Does this need to be changed?

Comment: `/etc/postfix/ssl/smtpd.cert` is missing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `/etc/postfix/main.cf` will contain the following three directives.

```
 smtpd_tls_cert_file=
 smtpd_tls_key_file=
 smtpd_use_tls=yes
```

This tells Postfix to use TLS.

You can get it working again by disabling TLS, or creating new certificates.

**Disabling TLS**

1. Change **smtpd_use_tls** from yes to no
2. /etc/init.d/postfix restart

**Creating new certificates**

1. Find the key file (according to **smtpd_tls_key_file**).  If it is missing, you will have to create a new one. (**openssl genrsa -out filename.key 1024; chmod 600 filename.key**)
2. Create a [CSR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certificate_signing_request) (**openssl req -new -key filename.key -out filename.csr**)
3. Create the certificate (**openssl x509 -req -days 730 -in filename.csr -signkey filename.key -out filename.crt**)
4. Make it into the .pem format (**cat filename.key filename.crt > filename.pem;chmod 600 filename.pem; chown postfix filename.pem**)

Then ensure it is where it needs to be according to **/etc/postfix/main.cf**, and restart Postfix. You should be good to go.

Comment: @Brent - Why change it to a .pem format? Any links explaining what differentiates a pem file from the other key file formats would be great. I've wondered this for a very long time.

Comment: Not sure why it uses a .pem format - that step may be unnecessary.  As you can see, the pem format is just a concatenation of the .key and .crt files.

Comment: Note that `smtp_use-tls` is now obsolete, should use `  smtpd_tls_security_level`, with value `may` to allow.

Answer (score 1):

It would appear as though you have an issue in "/etc/postfix/ssl/smtpd.cert", either the file is missing, the permissions on it are wrong, or the formatting of the certificate inside it is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem.  It turned out the name of my private key was mailserver.**pem** and yet in postfix's configuration it was mailserver.**key**.  I'd followed a tutorial which had both with a .pem extension.

I also had both the cert and private key readable only by root, and I changed this so that they were readable by both root and postfix (chown root:postfix filename; chmod 640 filename).  Not sure if this second step is required.