# Relay access denied and policy rejection errors

Tags: postfix

I have two different errors when receiving mail from this server mailserver.santanderrio.com.ar[200.61.38.105].

postfix/smtpd[23015]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from mailserver.santanderrio.com.ar[200.61.38.105]: 554 5.7.1 XXX@XXX.com: Relay access denied; from=mensajesyavisos@mails.santanderrio.com.ar to=XXX@XXX.com proto=ESMTP helo=rs6.mails.bancorio.com.ar

postfix/smtpd[2948]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from mailserver.santanderrio.com.ar[200.61.38.105]: 450 4.7.1 XXX@XXX.com: Recipient address rejected: Policy Rejection- Please try later.; from=newsletter@mails.santanderrio.com.ar to=XXX@XXX.com proto=ESMTP helo=rs7.ar.bsch

Conf =

```
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = reject_unknown_sender_domain,
                            reject_unknown_recipient_domain,
                            reject_non_fqdn_sender,
                            reject_non_fqdn_recipient,
                            reject_unlisted_recipient,
                            reject_rbl_client cbl.abuseat.org,
                            reject_rbl_client bl.spamcop.net,
                            reject_rbl_client sbl-xbl.spamhaus.org,
                            reject_rbl_client hostkarma.junkemailfilter.com=127.0.0.2,
                            permit_mynetworks,
                            permit_sasl_authenticated,
                            reject_unauth_destination,
                            reject_non_fqdn_helo_hostname,
                            reject_invalid_helo_hostname,
                            check_policy_service inet:127.0.0.1:10031
```

any ideas?

Comment: let me know if you need an additional data

Comment: I don't know anything about postfix but the first entry is a permanent failure and it looks like postfix doesn't know it's authorative for the domain of the intended recipient. The second entry is a transient (temporary) failure, maybe because of some problem with the recipient's mailbox.

Answer (score 1):

The first error message is just what it says, an attempt to relay mail through your system was rejected. Another ServerFault question touches on this, and may be of use:

[How to correct Postfix' 'Relay Access Denied'?](https://serverfault.com/questions/42519/how-to-correct-postfix-relay-access-denied-problem)

Comment: I was assuming that the recipient in the first entry was an internal recipient, but that may not be the case as you've stated.