# Fixing 'Relay access denied' in Postfix

Tags: email, postfix, configuration, alias

Before you claim about duplicates and so on, I've checked these topics:

- [Postfix "Relay access denied"](https://serverfault.com/questions/223041/postfix-relay-access-denied)
- [How to correct Postfix' 'Relay Access Denied'?](https://serverfault.com/questions/42519/how-to-correct-postfix-relay-access-denied-problem)

The above topics doesn't solve my problems, perhaps this is something to do with my configuration file which totally differs to one of the topics above, so I'm posting a new fresh topic.

I'm trying to set up Postfix to work with sending emails and mail aliases. If I send an email with my hotmail account to `developer@domain.com` I get a reply from hotmail saying:

```
This is an automatically generated Delivery Status Notification.

Delivery to the following recipients failed.

      developer@domain.com



Reporting-MTA: dns;blu0-omc4-s15.blu0.hotmail.com
Received-From-MTA: dns;BLU0-SMTP148
Arrival-Date: Thu, 10 Nov 2011 08:31:02 -0800

Final-Recipient: rfc822;developer@domain.com
Action: failed
Status: 5.7.1
Diagnostic-Code: smtp;554 5.7.1 <developer@domain.com>: Relay access denied

From: My name <myhotmail@HOTMAIL.CO.UK>
Subject: Testing
Date: 10 November 2011 16:30:58 GMT
To: developer@domain.com

This is a typical test
```

I already have the mail aliases set up, pointing to the correct emails and such.

This is the **/etc/postfix/main.cf** I have.

```
# See /usr/share/postfix/main.cf.dist for a commented, more complete version


# Debian specific:  Specifying a file name will cause the first
# line of that file to be used as the name.  The Debian default
# is /etc/mailname.
#myorigin = /etc/mailname

smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = no

# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

# See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
# information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.

myhostname = localhost
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
mydestination = $mydomain, $myhostname, localhost, localhost.localdomain, , localhost
#relayhost = 
relayhost = $mydomain

#mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mynetworks = 192.168.1.0/24 127.0.0.0/8

mailbox_command = procmail -a "$EXTENSION"
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
```

Here's an log when I sent an email:

```
Nov 10 18:29:42 website postfix/smtpd[3320]: connect from blu0-omc4-s8.blu0.hotmail.com[65.55.111.147]
Nov 10 18:29:42 website postfix/smtpd[3320]: BA882D90044: client=blu0-omc4-s8.blu0.hotmail.com[65.55.111.147]
Nov 10 18:29:42 website postfix/cleanup[3324]: BA882D90044: message-id=<BLU0-SMTP25173F66176C5CE09165FCE85DC0@phx.gbl>
Nov 10 18:29:42 website postfix/qmgr[3143]: BA882D90044: from=<myhotmail@hotmail.co.uk>, size=1107, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Nov 10 18:29:42 website postfix/cleanup[3324]: E91B9D90047: message-id=<BLU0-SMTP25173F66176C5CE09165FCE85DC0@phx.gbl>
Nov 10 18:29:42 website postfix/local[3325]: BA882D90044: to=<developer@domain.com>, relay=local, delay=0.29, delays=0.28/0.01/0/0, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (forwarded as E91B9D90047)
Nov 10 18:29:42 website postfix/qmgr[3143]: E91B9D90047: from=<myhotmail@hotmail.co.uk>, size=1231, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Nov 10 18:29:42 website postfix/qmgr[3143]: BA882D90044: removed
Nov 10 18:29:42 website postfix/smtp[3326]: warning: relayhost configuration problem
Nov 10 18:29:42 website postfix/smtp[3326]: E91B9D90047: to=<aliasedemailaddress@hotmail.co.uk>, orig_to=<developer@domain.com>, relay=none, delay=0.02, delays=0/0.01/0.02/0, dsn=4.3.5, status=deferred (mail for mail.domain.com loops back to myself)
Nov 10 18:29:43 website postfix/smtpd[3320]: disconnect from blu0-omc4-s8.blu0.hotmail.com[65.55.111.147]
```

After removing `relayhosts` line:

```
Nov 10 18:37:23 website postfix/smtpd[3596]: connect from blu0-omc4-s9.blu0.hotmail.com[65.55.111.148]
Nov 10 18:37:23 website postfix/smtpd[3596]: 7DD9DD90044: client=blu0-omc4-s9.blu0.hotmail.com[65.55.111.148]
Nov 10 18:37:23 website postfix/cleanup[3601]: 7DD9DD90044: message-id=<BLU0-SMTP2217B7713EBB05FB5F0BB985DC0@phx.gbl>
Nov 10 18:37:23 website postfix/qmgr[3595]: 7DD9DD90044: from=<myhotmail@hotmail.co.uk>, size=2223, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Nov 10 18:37:23 website postfix/cleanup[3601]: B1D59D90048: message-id=<BLU0-SMTP2217B7713EBB05FB5F0BB985DC0@phx.gbl>
Nov 10 18:37:23 website postfix/local[3602]: 7DD9DD90044: to=<developer@website.org>, relay=local, delay=0.32, delays=0.32/0/0/0, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (forwarded as B1D59D90048)
Nov 10 18:37:23 website postfix/qmgr[3595]: B1D59D90048: from=<myhotmail@hotmail.co.uk>, size=2347, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Nov 10 18:37:23 website postfix/qmgr[3595]: 7DD9DD90044: removed
Nov 10 18:37:23 website postfix/smtpd[3596]: disconnect from blu0-omc4-s9.blu0.hotmail.com[65.55.111.148]
Nov 10 18:37:24 website postfix/smtp[3603]: B1D59D90048: to=<aliasedemailaddress@hotmail.co.uk>, orig_to=<developer@website.org>, relay=mx4.hotmail.com[65.54.188.126]:25, delay=1.1, delays=0/0/0.51/0.55, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 mail from IP 94.75.251.47 soft failed sender ID check. Please ensure this IP is authorized to send mail on behalf of [hotmail.co.uk])
Nov 10 18:37:24 website postfix/qmgr[3595]: B1D59D90048: removed
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So and where did you specify for which domains Postfix should be responsible? Nowhere. This is why you get this error. Add your domain to the line of `mydestination`. And then you need at least a local user named `developer` or put an alias into /etc/aliases.

But you have to read this documentation as an absolute minimum before you start with Postfix: http://www.postfix.org/BASIC_CONFIGURATION_README.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I added `mydomain = domain.com` and changed `relayhost` to `relayhost = mail.$mydomain`. I get no more error mail from hotmail, but I don't see it in the aliased email inbox. Something wrong?

Comment: @YouBook Probably. But without log messages I can't help (new question!). I'm not that good at divination.

Comment: Ah yes, updated my post.

Comment: @YouBook Remove the line with `relayhost` (completely!).

Comment: Updated my post again.

Comment: Hotmail doesn't allow to receive mails that were sent by Hotmail. So you should **not** alias a local user back to Hotmail. This is _not_ the fault of Postfix but prevents spamming. Don't argue with me, discuss this with Microsoft.

Comment: LOL. I guess this solves the problem, just tested using Google mail, works well. Thanks!

Comment: I've spent last 6 hours trying to fix this. exact same config layout. Comments were the answer Thank You!